# new React-native flow setup

Tags: react-native, flowtype

hey guys After initiating a react-native app I noticed the .flowconfig file already in the project folder so I assumed that flow is ready to be used however when I ran `flow` in terminal I got the error "`.flowconfig:27 Unsupported option specified! (experimental.strict_type_args)`". Anyone know why?

I haven't changed anything within the .flowconfig file

my flow version is coming up as 0.23.0

Comment: I recommend you to upgrade to current version of flow

Comment: thanks for the reply i'll try that tonight.

Comment: so I updated it. and now I'm getting these errors.

`node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:160
160:       this._callbacks[this._callbackID++] = onFail;`